# Число с е преобразовать в нормальный вид

Tags: python

В базе данных есть числа с е-0, степени всегда разные, как привести такие числа в нормальный вид? Я искал информацию и находил, но только единичные решения, а мне нужно, чтобы все числа с разными степенями приводило в нормальный вид, например, число 6.935e-07 чтобы стало 0.0000006935. Я написал такую функцию, но она очень тупая, завязана на количестве нулей и походу сильно грузит, так как скрипт крашнулся с Memory Error, когда до нее дошел. Есть какое-то решение проще?

```
def check_normal_number(number):
    new_number = 0
    if 'e-' in str(number):
        zero_needed = int(str(number)[-1]) - 1
        z = int(number * (10 ** (int(str(number)[-1]) + 3)))
        new_number = f'0.{"0" * zero_needed}{z}'
    return new_number
```

UPD: Делюсь решением для тех, кто ищет, помогли в ответах:
{k} - это число знаков после запятой. Для числа в моем виде оно всегда будет = степень (7) + актуальное число знаков после запятой (3)
Откидываем все начиная с е, считаем количество знаков и отнимаем 2 (первый символ и точка) и прибавляем степень.

```
number = 6.935e-07  
k = len(str(number).split('e')[0]) - 2 + int(str(asks_volume[2])[-1])
number = f'{number:.{k}f}'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/658763/how-to-suppress-scientific-notation-when-printing-float-values

Comment: Так а числа вы получаете как числа или как строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это же вопрос представления. Если вам приходит именно число, то просто печатайте его в нужном вам виде:

```py
number = 6.935e-07
print(f'{number:.10f}')
# 0.0000006935
```

А если приходит строка, то просто преобразуйте её предварительно в число и точно так же печатайте:

```py
number = float('6.935e-07')
print(f'{number:.10f}')
# 0.0000006935
```

Собственно, `f-строки` можно и не печатать - это обычные строки, можете их куда хотите сохранять.

По вопросу из комментария - число знаков вывода можно тоже указать в переменной:

```py
number = float('6.935e-07')
k = 10
print(f'{number:.{k}f}')
```

Comment: Так дело в том, что у меня всегда разная степень (e-05, e-07, e-09 и т.д.), соответственно .10f тоже должен быть разным, можно как-то .10f завернуть в переменную? Я видел такой вариант решения, но у меня не получилось завернуть .10f в переменную

Comment: @xx1 Добавил код

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я неправильно переменную подставлял, в первый раз с таким сталкивался!

Answer (score 1):

6.935e-07 самая оптимальная форма записи, не нужно считать не значащие нули и т.п., но если есть острая необходимость есть не оптимальный вариант.

```
import math

print(f'{math.pi:50.50f} \n{math.e:50.50f} \n{6.935e-07:50.50f}')

3.14159265358979311599796346854418516159057617187500 
2.71828182845904509079559829842764884233474731445312 
0.00000069350000000000000938127613786532421613628685
```

Как видно у последнего числа есть мусор эти моменты нужно отслеживать.
Лучше использовать нормальную форму записи с мантиссой и порядком.

Answer (score 0):

Я еще поэкспериментировал и придумал сделать вот так:

```
if 'e-' in str(number):
    main_part = str(asks_volume[2]).replace('.', '').split('e')[0]
    zeros = int(str(asks_volume[2])[-1]) - 1
    number = f'0.{"0" * zeros}{main_part}'
```

Подходит под все варианты до e-09 степени. В моем случае больше 9 не бывает, но если кто решит взять такой вариант - то дополнительно это подкрутить несложно.
В чем суть моего варианта:
допустим число - 6.935e-07
main_part - удаляет точку и все, что после е
zeros - считает количество нулей, необходимое после запятой по формуле - последний знак (то есть, 7) минус 1
и в конце выводит 0.{нужное кол-во нулей}{основная часть}
Новый вариант - 0.0000006935